# Return one item of a nested array in nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to extract only one item in a nested array in a MongoDB.

Here's the model:

```
const docShema= new mongoose.Schema({
  value1: {
    type: String
  },
  mainArray: [{
    value2: {
      type: String
    },
    secondArray: [{
      subValue1: {
        type: String
      },
      subValue2: {
        type: String
      },
    }],
  }],
});
```

Here's what I tried:

```
Collection.findOne({ "value1": "somevalue", "mainArray.secondArray.subValue1": "A" }, { "mainArray.secondArray.$": 1 }).exec((err, result) => {
  res.status(200).send(result)
})
```

Here's what have been returned:

```
{
_id: "5ef39f491ece670db31f1f39",
mainArray: [
    {
    value2: "firstvalue",
    _id: "5ef39f491ece670db31f1f73",
    secondArray: [
       {
       subValue1: "A",
       subValue2: "Red",
       _id: "5ef39f491ece670db31f1f79"
       },
       {
       subValue1: "B",
       subValue2: "Blue",
       _id: "5ef39f491ece670db31f1f78"
       },
       {
       subValue1: "C",
       subValue2: "Green",
       _id: "5ef39f491ece670db31f1f77"
       }
      ]    
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, the complete item from the mainArray was returned. But I only want one item from the second array and then in a subsequent action I will update only the part returned. So fineOneAndUpdate can be used instead. I used findOne only for testing purpose.

Comment: is your main goal is to update the `secondArray` array?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array-filters` & update it in single query only.
Reference: [Positional update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)